# How to change the default window that a Emacs process is loaded into?

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I am testing the ESS mode for supporting R in Emacs. What I have done is pretty normal:

1. used emacs to edit an `.R` file (so emacs has two buffers, the upper one holding the .R file, and the lower one showing the Welcome view).
2. started a new R process with `M-x R`.

One strange behavior I noticed is that ESS loads the new R process into the same buffer where the `.R` source is loaded and therefore overriding it.

I all other modes I've seen, Emacs would load the new process into the "unused" Welcome buffer ("Welcome to GNU Emacs, ..."), instead the current window/buffer I am editing/evaluating.

Is there a way to change the behavior of this mode (`ess-version: 16.10-1 [elpa: 20170227.802]`, Emacs is 24.5) so that the new R process occupy the "usused" Welcome view/window?

Comment: Do a "C-x b" to see your buffers.  Emacs surely created a new one for its ESS session.   So your question, really, is about default display of new buffers.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks. But I had no problem looking for the hidden .R source buffer with `C-x b`. It's just that I wanted to have ESS take "unused" buffers like the Welcome frame first before taking useful ones like the .R file I am editing/evaluating, as with other Emacs modes such as python, SQLi. In these other modes, I didn't have to `C-x b` if I am evaluating a single source file.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel And you are right. I edited the title so the question is about the default window of new processes.